# In Django if we use google oauth why the email address are not added in the User model?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, django-allauth

In my Django app, I have a used google oauth2 for login, so when a user signs up, the first_name, last_name and username are automatically added to the `User` model and can be viewed through the admin panel. But the email addresses of the user are not being added, why is it so? **Is there any way we can add the email address to the `User` model when the user signs up using OAuth?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default (if you do not specify SCOPE), profile scope is requested, and optionally email scope depending on whether or not **`SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL`** is enabled. See [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#google).

Optionally, you can specify the scope to use as follows:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}
```

Valid scopes include: **email, phone, address, aq:name, aq:location**. The default is to request a user’s name, and email address if **`SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL=True`**. You can request and require a verified email address by setting `SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION=True` and `SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True`.

---

**UPDATE**

See also [configuration](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration) for `SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION`.

Comment: if setting `SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL=True` requests the email then what is`SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION=True` for?

Comment: @yogeshiitm, As `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION`, but for social accounts. Determines the email verification method during signup.